# Deploying XML resources to JBoss using Twiddle

Tags: jboss

We are moving to JBoss 5.1.0 with autodeployment disabled. Therefore, we need to use twiddle to do our deployments.

The only place I have got stuck is deploying .xml files. These files are independent of our .war/.ear files and contain things such as Log4J configuration. As an example, we have a file called myapp_log4j.xml which, if deployed by hand, would be deployed in conf. It would then be read using:

```
InputStream in = LoggerFactory.class.getResourceAsStream("/myapp_log4j.xml");
```

This works fine if the .xml file is placed in the conf folder directly.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
twiddle.sh invoke "jboss.system:service=MainDeployer" deploy /tmp/deployfiles/myapp_log4j.xml
```

What command should I use to make this file available using twiddle?

Answer (score 1):

./twiddle.sh -u userid -p password -s localhost invoke "jboss.system:service=MainDeployer" deploy /tmp/sample/mtours.war  *<-- location of the application*